# Data compression algorithm in chrome and chromium

Tags: google-chrome, browser, compression, chromium, algorithm

I was doing some research on browsers and I want to know what is data compression algorithm really mean in browser. and what are algorithm currently using in chrome, and chromium.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For less bandwith usage web servers serves compressed datas over HTTP. Supported compressions are told to the server by the browser in [Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) request header. In response, the server uses [Content-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) representation header to let the browser know which compression it is using. As of *Chromium 94.0.4606.54 Arch Linux*, it sends `gzip, deflate, br`. 'br' stands for [Brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli), successor of gzip.

In Chrome/Chromium, press CTRL+i to open developer tools. Click 'Network' and visit a webpage. From the list of connected domains, you can choose a domain and see what compression it used under section 'Response headers' in 'content-encoding' field. As of https://superuser.com, the content-encoding is gzip, i.e, the HTML, JS and CSS are served gzip-compressed.